# What is the complexity of this?

Tags: c, code-complexity

```
int Mystery(int N) {
  int Sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < i * i; j++)
      for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
        Sum++;
  return Sum;
}
```

I am learning about complexity, but don't know about this, anyone has any ideas?